# Coconut palm dried leaves

Tags: diagnosis, palm

I bought a coconut palm a few weeks ago. I placed it in my bedroom and it was doing fine. I noticed browning on the leaves 1 week ago. As of today,all of the leaves are dead dry. I checked the pot and the roots are fine. Well draining soil. Wet but not soaked potting medium. I changed the soil. Replanted the nut but the I guess a leaves are dead.

I misted the leaves daily. Temperature was always above 22 Celsius. Plenty of indirect sunlight after noon from a west facing window.

Can I cut the whole leaf growth from the nut, and pray to bring new leaves, or my plant is basically dead now?

Comment: Pictures please

Comment: Where do you live in the world?

Comment: Nature does not mist plants normally.  That tends to form lenses on the leaves possibly causing burns.  I think it's dead.